# for each day, count unique users for day and day-1, grouped by third column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of:

- **day** -> the day as integer the user did an action (eg. day = 1)
- **user_id** -> unique id identifying each user. (eg. user_id = 'a'
- **actions** -> type of action take (eg. action = 1)

**Objective:**

- For day=n:
- For each action:
- For days = (n, n-1) (today & yesteday)
- Count number of unique users that performed said action.

With the dataset below, for example:

**Q**: "How many users on day 2 did action 1 on day2 and day2-1 ?"

- on day = 2.
- for action =1
- count of unique users for day = 2, day =1 ->  a,b,c = 3

**My current soltuion**

I have made a solution with 2 for loops, However I think there is a better solution that I am missing, using groupby/apply/rolling. But am unable to find a  more concise solution.

here is the full code:

```py
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.DataFrame(
    { 
        "day"    :  [ 0,  1,  1,  2,  2,   3 ,  1,   2,   4,   4,   5],
        "user_id":  ['a','a','b','b','c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
        "actions" :  [ 1,  1 , 1,  1,  1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2] 
     
     } 
)

# current soltion with 2 for loops. 
unique_dictionary = {'action': [], 'day': [], 'unique_users_last_n_days': []} # store the results 
n_days = 1 # change the days previous you look at. 

for action in (list(df.actions.unique())):
  for day in (sorted(list(df.day.unique()))):
    mask_last_n_days = (day - df["day"] >=0) & (day - df["day"] <= n_days)  #only look at values that meet condition. 
    mask_action = df['actions'] == action
    unique_users_last_n_days = df[(mask_action) & (mask_last_n_days)]["user_id"].nunique() # get the unique users in the condition 
    # store result in dictionary.  
    unique_dictionary['action'].append(action) 
    unique_dictionary['day'].append(day)
    unique_dictionary['unique_users_last_n_days'].append(unique_users_last_n_days)

df_unique_users_last_n_days = pd.DataFrame(unique_dictionary)

print (df_unique_users_last_n_days)


-OUT
    action  day  unique_users_last_n_days
0        1    0                         1
1        1    1                         2
2        1    2                         3
3        1    3                         2
4        1    4                         1
5        1    5                         0
6        2    0                         0
7        2    1                         1
8        2    2                         2
9        2    3                         1
10       2    4                         2
11       2    5                         3
```

The solution should work with missing days in the day column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create list of `DataFrame`s by previous days by add n days and filter in [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), add to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and get number of missing values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html), last add missing combinations `actions, days` by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
n_days = 2 
minday = df['day'].min()
maxday = df['day'].max()

dfs = [(df.assign(day = df['day'].add(day))
         .loc[lambda x: x['day'].between(minday, maxday)]) for day in range(1,n_days+1)]
s = (pd.concat([df, *dfs])
        .groupby(['actions','day'])['user_id']
        .nunique())

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names)
df2 = s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df2)
    actions  day  user_id
0         1    0        1
1         1    1        2
2         1    2        3
3         1    3        3
4         1    4        2
5         1    5        1
6         2    0        0
7         2    1        1
8         2    2        2
9         2    3        2
10        2    4        2
11        2    5        3
```

Comment: thanks, does this solution work if I change the n_days (so for exmaple look at the previous 2 days) ?